# React: Toggle function in child component not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Essentially I am trying to create a checkbox UI — I'm trying to pass down a toggle function to be used by a list component.  But for some reason I can get the check to propagate but cannot uncheck it.

Here is my code:

This is the Parent (home) component:

```
import React from 'react';
import RecipeDetail from './RecipeDetail';
import RecipeList from './RecipeList';

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      recipes: [],
      favorites: [],
      currentRecipe: null,
    };
    this.onRecipeClick = this.onRecipeClick.bind(this);
    this.toggleFavorite = this.toggleFavorite.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`${API_URL}/v1/recipes`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(recipes =>
        this.setState({
          recipes,
        })
      );
  }

  onRecipeClick = id => {
    fetch(`${API_URL}/v1/recipes/${id}`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(recipe =>
        this.setState({
          currentRecipe: recipe,
        })
      );
  };

  toggleFavorite = id => {
    this.setState(({ favorites, ...state }) => {
      const idx = favorites.indexOf(id);
      if (idx !== -1) {
        return { ...state, favorites: favorites.filter(f => f.id !== id) };
      }
      return { ...state, favorites: [...favorites, id] };
    });
  };

  // prettier-ignore
  render() {
    var { recipes, favorites, currentRecipe } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <main className="px4 flex">
          <RecipeList
            recipes={recipes}
            favorites={favorites}
            style={{ flex: 3 }}
            onClick={this.onRecipeClick}
            onFavorited={this.toggleFavorite}
            />
          <RecipeDetail
            className="ml4"
            recipe={currentRecipe}
            style={{ flex: 5 }}
            />
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

And this is List component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// prettier-ignore
const RecipeList = props => (

    <div style={props.style}>
      <h2 className="h2"> Recipes </h2>
      <ul className="list-reset">
        {props.recipes.map(recipe => (
          <li
            className="py2 border-bottom border-bottom-dashed pointer"
            key={recipe.id}
            onClick={() => props.onClick(recipe.id)}
          >
            <span
              className="mr1"
              onClick={e => {
                e.stopPropagation();
                props.onFavorited(recipe.id);
              }}
              role="img"
              aria-label="favorite"
            >
            {props.favorites.includes(recipe.id) ?  '✅' : ''}
            </span>
            <span>{recipe.name}</span>
            <span>{recipe.category}</span>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );

RecipeList.propTypes = {
  recipes: PropTypes.array,
  favorites: PropTypes.array,
  onClick: PropTypes.func,
  className: PropTypes.string,
  style: PropTypes.object,
};

RecipeList.defaultProps = {
  recipes: [],
  favorites: [],
};

export default RecipeList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the recipe id to the `favorites` array, not objects with an `id` property.

You just need to compare the elements themselves with the passed in `id` in the `filter` method.

```
toggleFavorite = id => {
  this.setState(({ favorites }) => {
    const idx = favorites.indexOf(id);
    if (idx !== -1) {
      return { favorites: favorites.filter(f => f !== id) };
    }
    return { favorites: [...favorites, id] };
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (idx !== -1) {
    return { ...state, favorites: favorites.filter(f => f.id !== id) };
}`

Here you are traversing the array, using filter to check if an object with `f.id` is the same as the `id` param you're trying to add. That would be fine. However, when adding a new entry on the array, this is what you're doing:

`{ ...state, favorites: [...favorites, id] };`

You're not adding a new object, you're adding just the ID. Whenever you try to uncheck it, it'll fail.

Don't know the specifics to what you're trying to do, but I think you should accept the whole object as a param in your `toggleFavorite` function and then perform your equality checks.

It'd look like this:

```js
toggleFavorite = recipe => {
    this.setState(({ favorites, ...state }) => {
      const idx = favorites.indexOf(recipe.id);
      if (idx !== -1) {
        return { ...state, favorites: favorites.filter(f => f.id !== recipe.id) };
      }
      return { ...state, favorites: [...favorites, recipe] };
    });
  };
  
  // In your list component...
  
  <span
    className="mr1"
    onClick={e => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      props.onFavorited(recipe.id);
    }}
    role="img"
    aria-label="favorite"
  >
    {props.favorites.find((f) => f.id === recipe.id) ?  '✅' : ''}
  </span>
```